# Converting to xsl showing the stylesheet line

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to convert xml to html using a xsl transformation file.

test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl" ?>
<website>
  <header/>
  <content>
    <b>First Line</b>
  </content>
</website>
```

test.xsl:

```
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/website">
    <html>
        <head/>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="header|content/*"/>
        </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="header">
   <b>Header</b>
   <br/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The converted html file looks like this:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl" ><html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body><b>Header</b><br><b>First Line</b></body>
</html>
```

We see that everything transforms correctly but in the output the stylesheet line comes at the top. How can I get rid of it? I did this using IE and then did view source. Then I tried to use msxsl.exe to convert the file and got the same result.

If I remove the identity transform from the xsl file the problem goes away, but it does not transform the output correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an empty template to remove *processing instructions* such as `<?xml-stylesheet ?>` :

```
....
....

<xsl:template match="header">
    <b>Header</b>
    <br/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="processing-instruction()"/>
```

Comment: That solves the issue! can you recommend a reference for xsl, the other 10% always eludes me...